# filter XML file using match and starts-with

Tags: xml, xslt, match, startswith

I have an XML file that holds about 1000 users and has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="filter.xsl"?>
  <USERS>
    <USER>
      <ID>15492</ID>
      <USERNAME>0047</USERNAME>
      <ADDRESS>
        <FIRSTNAME>mr</FIRSTNAME>
        <LASTNAME>Dees</LASTNAME>
        <ORGANIZATION>WON Organization Name </ORGANIZATION>
        <EMAIL>email@address.com</EMAIL>
      </ADDRESS>
      <COMMERCEINFO>
        <PAYMENTMETHOD>MANUAL</PAYMENTMETHOD>
      </COMMERCEINFO>
      <ACCOUNT>
        <PASSWORD>72d7df914cc8806b2eb0fa0203f322d7</PASSWORD>
        <EXPIRES>1601-01-01</EXPIRES>
      </ACCOUNT>
       .
       .
       .
    </USER>
    <USER>
    ...
    </USER>
  </USERS>
```

I only need to see the users where the `<ORGANIZATION>` element starts with 'WON'. Using IE8 to open the XML file, the connected XSL file looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="USER[ADDRESS[ORGANIZATION[starts-with(.,'WON')]]]" />  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, using this the result I see in the page source of IE8 gives all users, the filter does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small adjustment to the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <users>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="USERS/USER[ADDRESS[ORGANIZATION[starts-with(.,'WON')]]]"/>
        </users>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="USER">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in only `<user>` nodes that have an ORGANIZATION that starts with 'WON'.

This will, however, not update the source itself. The way you have set it up now is for the browser to parse the XML using the provided XSLT. 
If you want the source to be transformed already, you'll have to use a serverside language like PHP, Java, ASP.Net etc. Those languages can do the XML/XSLT transformation for you, and output the resulting HTML as the source of the webpage.

Comment: Thanks, that gives in IE8 at least the correct view, but ... I hoped that the page source would also show me only the filtered items. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: not without using any server side code like PHP, Java, ASP.NET etc. Those languages can parse the XML/XSLT transformation and show only the output in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I found a nice online tool to parse the XML and get the output I needed: http://xslttest.appspot.com/

Comment: Ah, I see. You are just looking for the output of the transformation. Yes, there are quite a few online parsers that can do this